# Automatic scroll right google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script or setting in Google Sheet, where it will automatically scroll to the last column on the right. The only thing I found were scripts for automatic scrolling down, but I don't need that, I need to scroll all the way to the right, not down.
So, this is the script that I found, and it doing great job. I need something like this, but for the right side, to the last column in file.

```
function onOpen(){
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getSheets()[0].getName());
 sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Range correctly in the `sheet.setActiveRange` function. Check out the following script.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getSheets()[0].getName());
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn()));
}
```

Comment: This works well, but stops at column K. This is where the problem arises because the columns  up to column K are frozen. Can this be solved somehow or does the column have to be unfreeze  for the script to work?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  sh.hideColumns(1,sh.getLastColumn());
}
```